# join two tables on match and no match

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have two table

One is Catgory

```
Category Value
ABC      1
DEF      2
ALL      3
```

Second table Job

```
JOB  Category 
123  ABC
234  DEF
456  GGG
778  TTT
```

I need to add join these two table on Category. But I need Answer as below

```
JOB  VALUE
123  1
234  2
456  3  
778  3
```

Basically if category match then get value assigned to this. But if there is ALL in category column and have value then if category doesn't match then shows value for ALL for unmatched value as in example of job 456 and 778.

Comment: Hint: `LEFT JOIN`, `COALESCE()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two `left join`s:

```
select j.*, coalesce(c.value, c_default.value) as value
from job j left join
     category c
     on j.category = c.category left join
     category c_default
     on c_default.category = 'ALL';
```

You could also use a correlated subquery:

```
select j.*,
       (select c.value
        from category c
        where c.category in ('ALL', j.category)
        order by (c.category = j.category) desc
        limit 1
       ) as value
from job j;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `outer join` and `coalesce`

```
select job, Coalesce(c.value, (select value from category where category='ALL')) as value
from job j
left join category c on c.category=j.category
```

You could also use a `window function` to rank matching and non matching categories

```
with j as (
    select j.job, c.value, Row_Number() over(partition by job order by case when c.category='all' then 1 else 0 end) rn
    from job j
     join category c on c.category=j.category or c.category='ALL'  
)
select job,value
from j
where rn=1
```